# How to use set and enum together?

Tags: c++

I just started coding in c++. My first task is to create set of an enum and pass string values in set using enum values as keys for each string value. I have no idea how to do that.

my best guess.

```
typedef enum sendDataElements
{
    Data1,
    Data2,
    Data3,
    Data4,
}
std::set<string, sendDataElements> m_modules;
m_modules.insert(message, Data1);
```

Doesn't compile though. Please help.

Comment: You're most probably looking for a std::map, not std::set.
std::set is a container that holds only keys, but not values

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need that `typedef enum ...` dance (even if it was written correctly). That's a C-ism. Drop the `typedef`.

Comment: Missing semicolon after typedef. Next...

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    enum SendDataElements
    {
        SEND_DATA_1,
        SEND_DATA_2,
        SEND_DATA_3,
        SEND_DATA_4,
    };

    std::map<std::string, SendDataElements> modules;
    modules["poop"] = SEND_DATA_1;
}
```

As others have said in the comments of your original question, std::set only accepts keys, while you are trying to store keys and values. You are probably looking to use a map. I also updated the style of your enum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here, if i print SEND_DATA_1 or modules["poop"] then both will give me 0 value. I want to use my enum as key values and add my data for each key. For example, if SEND_DATA_1 = "ABC", "SEND_DATA_2" = "CDE". How can i achieve that?

Comment: @RookieDev If I understand right, you want the enum to be the key and the string to be the value. Change the map to 'std::map<SendDataElements, std::string> modules;' and the assignment to 'modules[SEND_DATA_1] = "ABC";'

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the enums SEND_DATA_1 is 0, SEND_DATA_2 is 1, etc. Enums evaluate to integral values. What you will want to evaluate is the elements in your map after you initialize the map and set up all your associations with the strings you want.